# Patching and compiling kernel, in which directory

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to apply a patch to my kernel source with limited success. The target machine is really some ARM device, but I haven't compiled a kernel before so I thought I'd start with an x86_64 kernel. This has been only marginally easier :)

Now, according to some tutorials, it seemed like we should use the source in `/usr/src/linux-something`. But when I tried to patch there I got

```
File Documentation/sysrq.txt is read-only; trying to patch anyway
patch: **** Can't create temporary file Documentation/sysrq.txt.oG1oiZW : Permission denied
```

even under sudo. So I tried just copying the patch and the linux source folder to my home directory and patched it from there. This worked. Why is this and will this have any weird side effects when compiling?

Comment: May I ask you to add a link to the tutorial that says to use `/usr/src` for compiling the kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have no permission to `/usr/src/linux-something`. Download kernel source, put it anywere you could, then patch & compile it.

Build a x86_64 arch kernel from source which downloaded from [kernel.org](http://kernel.org) is well, if you wanna build an arm arch kernel for a special board, use [buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) or [openwrt](https://openwrt.org/) is better.

Answer (score 0):

The package manager for some distributions installs the kernel source in `/usr/src` and distribution-specific build scripts may assume that the source is in that directory.

However, if you download vanilla kernel source from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/), you should be able to build it anywhere.